# Is $\frac{1}{n-1}$ a convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm studying the proof of the fact that "all convergent sequences must be bounded", which goes something like this (loosely speaking):

> For all $\epsilon \gt 0$ we can find a natural number $k$ such that all terms of the sequence beyond $k$ would be "close to" $x$, the value to which the sequence converges.

Next, we define $M(m)$ = maximum (minimum) of the first $(k-1)$ elements and $x$. Therefore we can say all terms of the sequence are within the range $m$ to $M$.

> However my question is, what about the first $(k-1)$ terms? How do we make sure they're all finite?

I understand $k$ could be decreased by increasing $\epsilon$, but that does not ensure $all$ terms tend to $x$ for $all$ $n$ (i.e. even terms towards the beginning of the sequence like the $1^{st}$, $2^{nd}$ term etc.).

> E.g. what about the sequence $\cfrac{1}{n-1}$. It's not defined at $n=1$. However from $n=2$ onwards all subsequences are convergent. So can we say it is convergent? If yes, we find all terms are bounded but the first term is not, which is not in line with the proof above, because the proof seems to assume all the first $(k-1)$ terms are bounded for all $k$ corresponding to any $\epsilon$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes. The first finitely many terms of a sequence don't matter as for convergence.

Comment: i) by definition every individual term in a sequence by definition is a real number; there are no unbounded terms so ii) 1/(n-1) can not have 1/0 as a term.  The sequence simply starts at 1/(2-1) which leads to iii) the n in $a_n $ is just an index; it does nesc define the sequence;  {1/(n-1)} is the same sequence as {1/n}, you've only changed the index.  iv) any 1 or any finite terms of the sequence have absolutely nothing to do with the rest of the terms. The first gazillion terms can jump about like a flea; all that matters is what the infinite terms "tend to" "after a while".

Comment: The sequence $\{ 1/(n-1)\}_{n \ge 1}$ IS NOT a sequence of real numbers.  All classic result deal with sequences of real numbers.

Comment: A sequence is an ordered set of numbers each of which, being a number, has to be finite. It's the numbers, not the description, that is important. If I make up a rule to define a sequence and I do it badly so that the results aren't all numbers, I don't have a sequence with some terms not numbers; I have simply ... a poorly defined mess.  E.g I can't say let $a_n = 1/(n \mod 4) $ be a sequence because every fourth term is undefined.

Comment: You  are looking at $(1/k)_{k \geq 2}$ if you remove the first term. The sequence converges with respect to the usual norm.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence

$$n\in\mathbb N:a_n=\frac1{n-1}$$

isn't defined, you can't discuss its convergence.

The sequence

$$n\in\mathbb N, n>1:a_n=\frac1{n-1}$$

is bounded in range $(0,1]$.

A finite number of defined terms is always bounded.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to realize a sequence is a countable set of numbers  presented in an order.  The terms can be anything.

Say {q,x,d,o,m,n....}

That we present these terms as {$a_1,a_2,a_3,.... $} so that each term has a distinct index $i $ is a matter of convience and not anything intrinsic about the terms themselves.

We can't take a sequence intrinsically being {1,1/3,1/5,1/7,...} and say "this is the sequence when $a_i = 1/i $ and $i $ is odd".  That simply doesn't make any sense.  The terms are what they are and the variable $a_i $ are simply the variables listed in order.  You can't say "there is only a first, third and fifth term but there is no second or fourth or any evenly indexed term".  That just doesn't make sense.

The terms are whatever we label them.

Likewise there can't be a sequence {5/6, 1,5/4,5/3,5/2,5, infinity, -5, -5/3,...}

That's not a sequence because infinity is not a number.  That I can match it up with a function $f (x) = 5/(7 - x)$ and I can say "let $a_n = 5/(7-n) $"  doesn't mean I've magically made something impossible happen.  It just means I've created something ill-defined.